# How insert large amount of data (about 1 million records) per minutes into MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, nosql, bigdata, bulkinsert

I want to insert about 1 million records per minutes into a single server MongoDB database. I have index on 6 fields. When the database was empty, I could insert data rapidly in  less than a minute into my collection (using bulk insert and multi-processing). However, as the size of data in collection increased, the insertion speed greatly decreased. Is there any idea that how can I handle such data insertion?
(my data is about price changes)
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Indexes are beneficial in case of find operations where in it performs fast retrieval of documents contained into database but indexes should be created on those fields only which are used as filters for retrieval of selected information.Defining too many indexes result into overhead of insert and update operations as with every insert and update operation those modified records need to be added into index data structure too.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, Indexing is expensive. However, I had to index my data. Because I need fast reports such as minimum/maximum/average of prices over day/week/month for a specific flight/path/airline (my data is about flights' price changes).

Answer (score 0):

Figure out what your bottleneck is and address it.

Is the server CPU or disk bound? Increase CPU speed or add IOPS to disk.

What proportion of time is used for index writes? Remove all indexes and measure insertion rate at current data size, then add one index at a time while measuring insertion rate with each index addition.

Is insertion rate decreasing linearly with data set size growth? Faster or slower?

MongoDB exposes many server statistics, look through them and identify the ones relevant to throughput, see if you spot any patterns.

Comment: The bottleneck is CPU, because when the size of data in collection increase, it had to do a lot of process in order to index data.

Comment: I am referring to *observing* what the bottleneck is, not hypothesizing or guessing. Your hypotheses/guesses may be correct or may be wrong.

Comment: I did not say it is my hypotheses/guesses! I said the bottleneck!

Comment: I do not see any evidence pointing to this in the question.